# Class _NSZombie__GEOTileKeyWrapper is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: iphone, debugging, nszombie

I have this message while debugging my app:

> Class *NSZombie*_GEOTileKeyWrapper is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Do you know what is this? And how to fix it?

Comment: I hit this in heavy multi-threaded code. I am starting 50 threads as part of a test. I suspect that the runtime has some issues with the zombies in that case. In most cases this is benign, but I did observe a deadlock while draining the autorelease pools in those threads. If it doesn't impact your code you can ignore it.

Answer (score 12):

This happens when you have two implementations of the same class and Obj-c runtime is unable to decide which one to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore this particular message.

The reason you can ignore it, is because it says:

> Class **NSZombie_**....

Which means that the object to which the message is referring is a dummy object created by Xcode Diagnostics. Read more about [Zombies here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/EradicatingZombies.html). The message should not appear if you disable `Zombie Objects` in your environment diagnostics options.

[image]

Comment: After half a year, I am also encountering this issue in XCode 9.3.1. I am developing this app since 2010, and have never seen this error, even with zombie objects enabled. Now I did some tricky stuff with EKEvent loading in background queues, and I am wondering if this message can **actually be ignored** and XCode is generating this false positive, or if theres actually a more severe issue in my code? How could I find this out?